# Train function from R caret package error: "Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing"

Tags: r, r-caret

I want to run a `logreg` regression. I obtain the following error after running my code on R:

Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:

```
    Accuracy       Kappa    
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :9     NA's   :9    
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) : Stopping
In addition: There were 19 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
```

Here is my code:

```
## Data
donner <- read.delim("http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/760/data/donner.txt")
set.seed(1234)
library(caret)
donner$Age <- as.numeric(donner$Age)
donner$Status <- as.factor(donner$Status)  
donner$Sex <- as.numeric(donner$Sex) 
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(donner$Status, p = .80, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainDF <- donner[splitIndex,]
testDF <- donner[-splitIndex,]
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 2)
logregmodel <- train(Status ~ ., data = donner, method = "logreg", trControl = ctrl)
```

EDIT 1:

I changed the status to binary (0 and 1) and I still have some errors. Here is the new code:

```
## Data
donner <- read.delim("http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/760/data/donner.txt")
set.seed(1234)
library(caret)
donner$Age <- as.numeric(donner$Age)
donner$Status <- as.integer(donner$Status)-1  
donner$Sex <- as.numeric(donner$Sex)-1 
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(donner$Status, p = .80, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainDF <- donner[splitIndex,]
testDF <- donner[-splitIndex,]
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 2)
donner$Status <- as.factor(donner$Status)
logregmodel <- train(Status ~ ., data = donner, method = "logreg", trControl = ctrl)
```

Comment: Are you sure you are fitting the model right? If you check the error, it also says non-binary arguments among predictors
https://github.com/topepo/caret/blob/master/RegressionTests/Code/logreg.R

Comment: I want to fit a logistic regression model. The outputs can only take two values.

Comment: You are correct about the output. But look carefully at @ Hack-R's code, the predictor `Age` is changed to binary. I don't see that in your edit.

Comment: The problem is that I lose some information if I don't keep the age as numeric. Normally, I should be able to use continuous variables for logistic regression. How can I do this?

Comment: Oh okay so you didn't really want a `logreg` (LOGIC regression) you just wanted a logit model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've personnaly never used the "logreg" method. It also seems that some lines are useless. Here is my suggestion using "glm" as a method.

```
## Data
donner <- read.delim("http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/760/data/donner.txt")

set.seed(1234)
library(caret)

donner$Age <- as.numeric(donner$Age)
donner$Status <- as.factor(donner$Status)
donner$Sex <- as.numeric(donner$Sex)-1 

splitIndex <- createDataPartition(donner$Status, p = .80, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainDF <- donner[splitIndex,]
testDF <- donner[-splitIndex,]

ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)
logregmodel <- train(Status ~ ., data = trainDF, method = "glm", family='binomial', trControl = ctrl)

summary(logregmodel)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just needed to fix your data. Logic Regression -- which is what I'm assuming you want, since you called the logic regression (`logreg`) method and this entire question is aside from the point if you're wanting something else like logit model, which would never give you the error in the first place -- is for binary variables only *and* it doesn't understand that 1's and 2's can represent binary data. It wants literal 0's and 1's.

```
donner <- read.delim("http://web.as.uky.edu/statistics/users/pbreheny/760/data/donner.txt")
set.seed(1234)
library(caret)
donner$Age <- as.numeric(donner$Age)
donner$Status <- as.factor(donner$Status)  
donner$Sex <- as.numeric(donner$Sex) 
splitIndex <- createDataPartition(donner$Status, p = .80, list = FALSE, times = 1)
trainDF <- donner[splitIndex,]
testDF <- donner[-splitIndex,]
ctrl <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 3)
donner$Status <- as.character(donner$Status)
donner$Status[!donner$Status == "Survived"] <- 0
donner$Status[donner$Status == "Survived"] <- 1
donner$Age_gr_mean <- 0
donner$Age_gr_mean[donner$Age_gr_mean > mean(donner$Age)] <- 1
donner$Age <- NULL
donner$Status <- as.numeric(donner$Status)
donner$Sex[donner$Sex == 2] <- 0
logregmodel <- train(Status ~ ., data = donner, method = "logreg", trControl = ctrl)
```

Comment: I tried to run your code and my R console froze. However, I tried to implement your suggestion and I still have an error. I will edit the question.

Comment: @user6496985 I didn't have any errors; the model completed. If your console froze that's because you need to increase CPU/RAM. There are a number of ways to do this. Make sure you're using 64-bit. I ran this on an 8GB RAM, dualcore CPU laptop (while watching a movie on Google Play) so I don't them the resource requirements are too much for most laptops with proper settings in R to maximize allowable RAM usage.